# How to create specefic columns out of text in r

Tags: r

Here is just an example I hope you can help me with, given that the input is a line from a `txt` file, I want to transform it into a table (see output) and save it as a `csv` or `tsv` file.

I have tried with separate functions but could not get it right.

Input

```
"PR7 - Autres produits d'exploitation 6.9 371 667 1 389"
```

Desired output

| Variable | note | 2020 | 2019 | 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PR7 - Autres produits d'exploitation | 6.9 | 371 | 667 | 1389 |

Comment: @AniGoyal I realize that you thought you were helping by editing this to include the image, but it was entirely wasted effort. It adds nothing to the value of the question. The questioner needed to be told NOT to add images of data. Instead they should have been referred to one of the many SO pages where the Totally Correct Way To Add Data to SO have been described.

Comment: Hello, I would probably start reading such data with something like `read.table(text = "PR7 - Autres produits d'exploitation 6.9 371 667 1 389")`. Assuming that all this data comes from a single file containing "lines" of text, I would probably comine it with the function `readLines`.

Comment: @Omar Hmissi : just a quick question that might save you from a lot of dirty coding: do you have the same data as an Excel file? I think it has to exist somewhere because I'm 95% sure that nobody could be insane enough to create this badly delimited dataset.

Comment: @Vincent Guillemot no actually i made an ocr of a pdf (image pdf) it's in a table format                            bt_text<-pdf_ocr_text(pdf1,pages = 1,language = "fra",dpi = 600)                                                                                                                        bt_txt <- readLines(con=textConnection(bt_text))                                                                          and then i extract the line that im intersted in :PR7 <- bt_txt[grep("Autres produits d'exploitation",bt_txt,fixed = F)]  and that's where i've come to ask this question

Comment: OK that makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this badly delimited data-set is the only place where you can read your data.

I created for the purpose of this answer an example file (that I called `PR.txt`) that contains only the two following lines.

```
PR6 - Blabla 10 156 3920 245
PR7 - Autres produits d'exploitation 6.9 371 667 1389
```

First I create a function to parse each line of this data-set. I'm assuming here that the original file does not contain the names of the columns. In reality, this is probably not the case. Thus this function that could be easily adapted to take a first "header" line into account.

```
readBadlyDelimitedData <- function(x) {
  # Read the data
  dat <- read.table(text = x) 
  # Get the type of each column
  whatIsIt <- sapply(dat, typeof)
  # Combine the columns that are of type "character"
  variable <- paste(dat[whatIsIt == "character"], collapse = " ")
  # Put everything in a data-frame
  res <- data.frame(
    variable = variable,
    dat[, whatIsIt != "character"])
  # Change the names
  names(res)[-1] <- c("note", "Year2021", "Year2020", "Year2019")
  return(res)
}
```

Note that I do not call the columns with the yearly figure by only "numeric" names because giving rows or columns purely "numerical" names  is not a good practice in R.

Once I have this function, I can (`l`)apply it to each line of the data by combining it with `readLines`, and collapse all the lines with an `rbind`.

```
out <- do.call("rbind", lapply(readLines("tests/PR.txt"), readBadlyDelimitedData))
out
                              variable note Year2021
1                         PR6 - Blabla 10.0      156
2 PR7 - Autres produits d'exploitation  6.9      371
  Year2020 Year2019
1     3920      245
2      667     1389
```

Finally, I save the result with `read.csv` :

```
read.csv(out, file = "correctlyDelimitedFile.csv")
```

---

If you can get your hands on the Excel file, a simple `gdata::read.xls` or `openxlsx::read.xlsx` would be enough to read the data.

I wish I knew how to make the script simpler... maybe a `tidyr` magic person would have a more elegant solution?